# Parsing Xml file using Java throws Exception. Why?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

While I was trying to get the attribute of the root element Company I found the following problems, also some exceptions.

But I imported everything I need; then also eclipse says that remove unused import.

I want to know that why it is happening even after i have imported everything,
please give me some idea to remove the bug.

Also is it the way to do xml-parsing? is there any alternative and easy way to
do the same?

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;

public class DomTest1 {
    private static final String file = "test1.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length>0) {
            file = args[0];
        }

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document=builder.parse(new File(file));
            Element root=document.getDocumentElement();
            System.out.println(root.getTagName());
            System.out.printf("name: %s%n", root.getAttribute("name"));
            System.out.printf("sHortname: %s%n", root.getAttribute("sHortname"));
            System.out.printf("mission : %s%n", root.getAttribute("mission"));
        } catch(EOFException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.w3c.dom.Element to javax.lang.model.element.Element
The method getTagName() is undefined for the type Element
The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type Element
The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type Element
The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type Element

at DomTest1.main(DomTest1.java:23)
```

Comment: you need to import Element from org.w3c.dom.Element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have

```
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
```

but you want

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

instead.

Also, regarding this:

> also is it the way to do xml-parsing? is there any alternative and
>   easy way to do the same?

You are using java out of the box-provided ways to do xml parsing. There are several, better alternatives using 3rd part libraries. I'd recommend testing [jdom](http://www.jdom.org/), it is a lot simpler. See example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/).

Comment: ... "you have" it even *twice*"

Comment: Okay.. but Now in the line Element element=document.getDocument Element. But Eclipse suggested me as "Add Cast to elements" why? where is the bug?

Answer (score 0):

problem is because of this

```
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
```

use this import statement

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element
```

Comment: then what should i do? remove that import?

Comment: You should simply replace `import javax.lang.model.element.Element;` with `import org.w3c.dom.Element;`